# Made a light controller for the holidays

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, pins, relay, switch

I am a new the world of Arduino. I found on YouTube, how to build a light controller [(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvG9c84ApFA&t=39s).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvG9c84ApFA&t=39s.) I follow every step but it doesn't work. Here are some pictures and a rough schematic. (I don't have a Arduino, it is a Egeloo mega 2560)[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvG9c84ApFA&t=39s.)

[image: elegoo Arduino mega 2560 r3]

[image: shematic]

[image: board two]

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what doesn't work? Where do the orange and black dashed lines go to? What relay boards are you using? What power supply are you using for the relay boards? What code did you use? You might want to try testing with only a single board.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a poor problem description, like asking "my car doesn't work. Whats wrong?". Please describe, what you did, what you expected and what happend instead. Also remove the images of your big wiring (we cannot see anything on that). Include a link to the used relay boards and your code.